# Android listview columns based on spinner's selection

Tags: android, listview, spinner

another question of mine.

I have created a screen that consists of a Spinner and a Listview. The Spinner takes only 2 values and the Listview is populated accordingly to the Spinner's selection.The problem is that I want the Listview to have 2 or 3 columns (based on the Spinners selection), how can i achieve that?

Or to say it in other words, is there a way to hide/show a column of a listview on the fly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be to have a tablerow with 3 elements as a child of the listview.

Another option could be to use a gridview if you want columns instead of a listview, or a table maybe.